# What's wrong with this calculation involving pullbacks of divisors on surfaces?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Beauville, *Complex Analytic Surfaces*, Proposition I.8(b), reads:

> Let [S and] $S'$ be a surface, $g : S \to S'$ a generically finite morphism of degree $d$, and $D$ and $D'$ divisors on $S$.  Then $g^\ast D . g^\ast D' = d(D.D')$.

[ Unless I'm *really* missing something -- almost anything seems possible to me right now -- that should say that $D$ and $D'$ are divisors on $S'$.  I'm assuming that's just a typo. ]

This bothers me, for the following reason.

Take $S = S' = \mathbb{P}^2$.  Let $d$ be a positive integer which is not a perfect square.  Define
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}^2 & \xrightarrow{g} \mathbb{P}^2 \\
    [x_0:x_1:x_2] & \mapsto [x_0^d : x_1^d : x_2^d ]
\end{align}
so that $g$ is a finite morphism of degree $d$.  Let $D$ be a line on $\mathbb{P}^2$.  Then we have $(D . D) = 1$, so the theorem claims that $(g^\ast D . g^\ast D) = d$.

However, $g^\ast D$ is a divisor on $\mathbb{P}^2$, so it's linearly equivalent to some multiple of a line, say $g^\ast D = e D$.  It follows that $(g^\ast D . g^\ast D) = e^2$.

Therefore, $d = e^2$.  But $d$ was not a perfect square by assumption.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Maybe I'm confused too, but why is $g$ a degree $d$ map? Letting $\omega$ be a primitive *d*th root of unity, you have that if for $[x_0:y_0:z_0] \in \mathbf{P}^2$, and a choice $r_0,s_0,t_0$ of *d*th roots of $x_0,y_0,z_0$, respectively, then $[\omega^{a_0} r_0:\omega^{a_1} s_0:\omega^{a_2} t_0]$ is a point in the preimage for any triple $(a_0,a_1,a_2)$ where $0 \le a_i < d$ for all $i$. There are (generically) $d^2$ of these, since $[\omega^{a_0} r_0:\omega^{a_1} s_0:\omega^{a_2} t_0] = [\omega^{b_0} r_0:\omega^{b_1} s_0:t_0]$ for some other $b_0,b_1$.

Comment: Ah, so is the degree of every generically finite map $\mathbb{P}^2 \to \mathbb{P}^2$ a perfect square?

Comment: Looks like it, and you can even replace the target with $S$ any surface with some divisor of self-intersection $1$.

Comment: Why don't you add that as an answer to get this off the open questions list?

Comment: Same argument: this sends $D(x_0) \simeq \mathbb{A}^2$ to itself and the inclusion $k[u^d, v^d] \subset k[u, v]$ definitely has degree $d^2$. [You are not alone in finding this book confusing. The plan is beautiful but kept very secret.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just my comment, with some renaming of variables.

The point is that $g$ is not a degree $d$ map. Letting $\omega$ be a primitive $d$th root of unity, you have that if for $[x_0:x_1:x_2] \in \mathbf{P}^2$, and a choice $r_0,r_1,r_2$ of $d$th roots of $x_0,x_1,x_2$, respectively, then $[\omega^{a_0}r_0 : \omega^{a_1}r_1 : \omega^{a_2}r_2]$ is a point in the preimage of $[x_0:x_1:x_2]$ for any triple $(a_0,a_1,a_2)$ where $0 \le a_i < d$ for all $i$. There are (generically) $d^2$ of these, since $[\omega^{a_0}r_0 : \omega^{a_1}r_1 : \omega^{a_2}r_2] = [\omega^{b_0}r_0 : \omega^{b_1}r_1 : r_2]$ for some other $b_0,b_1$.